# I recently updated to Visual Studio 16.5.0 Preview 2.0 and I'm getting a fatal error when debugging an Azure Function project

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

I recently updated to Visual Studio 16.5.0 Preview 2.0 and I'm getting the following error.

I'm trying to debug a project for an Azure Function. Has anyone encountered this before?

> A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated. The
>   debugger was configured to use the desktop CLR (.NET FRAMEWORK)
>   Managed debugger, but the target process loaded the CoreCLR (.NET
>   CORE) runtime. To debug this project, configure it to use the 'Managed
>   (CoreCLR)' debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3663#issuecomment-534055655) about this.

Please try follow the steps to configure it to use the 'Managed (CoreCLR)' debugger.

In Visual studio -> Debug menu -> Attach to Process -> in "Attach to" field, click the "select" button -> then in the "Debug those code types", select "Managed (CoreCLR)".

The screenshot as below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please help accept it as answer. Otherwise, please let me know the further issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ivan but I don't have Managed (CoreCLR) in my list. I have tried both VS 16.5.0 Preview2 and 16.4.3. Do you know why this might be the case and how I can add it?

Comment: @PatrickNolan, I tried with 16.4.3, it's there. But I don't know why it is not listed at your side:(.